# Get array from socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio

I'm finding a way to get an array, each component can have value between 0 and 255.
I'm using Android Studio and I received data from a socket. The following is my code.

```
try {
            InetAddress IpAddress = InetAddress.getByName(remoteName);
            myUpd_socket = new DatagramSocket(remotePort);
            // Send connect message
            String str = "connect request";
            send_data = str.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket send_packet = new DatagramPacket(send_data,str.length(), IpAddress, remotePort);
            myUpd_socket.send(send_packet);
            byte[] dataArray = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket udp_packet = new DatagramPacket(dataArray,dataArray.length);

            while (true) {
                myUpd_socket.receive(udp_packet);
                byte[] buff = new byte[udp_packet.getLength()];
                System.arraycopy(dataArray,0,buff,0,buff.length);
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I need to get the same data from the transmitter. There is no negative value in original data. But when I checked the received data, the buff has a lot of negative values. I made something wrong here.
I'm a newbie of Java and android. So I'm really grateful if someone can help me.
Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use:

**RECEIVE**

```
Socket socket = ...
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

int length = in.readInt();                    // read length of incoming message
if(length>0) {
    byte[] message = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(message, 0, message.length); // read the message
}
```

**SEND**

```
byte[] message = ...
Socket socket = ...
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

out.writeInt(message.length); // write length of the message
out.write(message);           // write the message
```

Answer (score 0):

`byte`s are signed in Java. If you want the unsigned value (as an `int`), use this: `byteValue & 0xFF`.